# How to signify that the bot is offline by using the discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am building a discord bot thats written in Python, and I just need to know how to let the server know the bot is offline by using the bot. Kinda like this: the bot sends a message to the general channel saying the bot is offline, then it shuts off. This is what I have for code:

```
@client.event
async def on_disconnect():
  general_channel = client.get_channel(general_channel_id)
  await general_channel.send('Discord protection bot is offline...')
```

I have tried looking up how to do this, but I can't find anything. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not possible, logically if you think about it, the code does not know its going to be shut down and would not be able to call a function prior to a shutdown.

Unless you shutdown your bot within the code itself, but operations you want to complete must be handled before the bot logs out/shutdown.

```
@client.command()
async def shutdown(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Discord protection bot is offline...")
        await client.logout()
```

From that the bot also cannot start up itself even after a set amount of time, unless you re-run the terminal